# How to sort datetime column in datatable (PHP)

Tags: sorting, datetime, datatables

I have this in my datatable, and in my query, i order it by latest creation date, and in datatable i also sort with the date column which is the 16th column in my datatable, but it does not sort according my need.

may i know how to sort the date so that it populate correct information for me?

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var asInitVals = new Array();
        var oTable = $('.datatable').DataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                            "sProcessing": "Loading data..."
                        },
            "bSortCellsTop": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "bLengthChange" : false,
            "aLengthMenu": {{ Config::get('crud.aLengthMenu') }},
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aaSorting": [[16, 'desc']],
            "sAjaxSource": "{{ url('someurl.ajax') }}",

            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                 "visible": false,
                 "searchable": false
             }]
    });
```

Comment: Uncertain what that javascript code is intended to show. Would be better if you show us your query.

Comment: `but it does not sort according my need` What exactly is your need?

Comment: The 16th column is actually the 17th column. Datatables uses a 0-index meaning that the first column is actually 0 and not 1. Have you accounted for this?